# How do I perform a calculation for every row in a DF while referencing data present on some other row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for an efficient way to calculate new column data (for every row), using information that may be present on some other row.

Here is an exemplary subset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'baseSeq': {0: 'ADTPICR', 1: 'ADTPICR', 2: 'AVALFAED', 3: 'AVALFAED', 4: 'AVALFAED', 5: 'AVALFAED', 6: 'AVALFAED', 7: 'AVALFAED'}, 'modSeq': {0: 'ADT[+16]PICR', 1: 'ADTPICR', 2: 'AVALFAED[+16]', 3: 'AVALFAE[+16]D', 4: 'AVALFAED', 5: 'AVALFAED[-30]', 6: 'AVALFAED', 7: 'AVALFAED'}, 'charge': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 3, 7: 4}, 'modType': {0: 'hydoxy', 1: 'UNMOD', 2: 'hydroxy', 3: 'hydroxy', 4: 'UNMOD', 5: 'decarbox', 6: 'UNMOD', 7: 'UNMOD'}, 'area_0': {0: 1862, 1: 22737, 2: 40060, 3: 40131, 4: 21962, 5: 12, 6: 21885, 7: 2116}, 'area_25': {0: 2472, 1: 30966, 2: 2423, 3: 2407, 4: 34387, 5: 16, 6: 35444, 7: 3072}, 'area_50': {0: 3015, 1: 24660, 2: 3553, 3: 3577, 4: 29860, 5: 40, 6: 33511, 7: 2974}})
```

```
     baseSeq          modSeq  charge    modType  area_0  area_25  area_50
0    ADTPICR    ADT[+16]PICR       2     hydoxy    1862     2472     3015
1    ADTPICR         ADTPICR       2      UNMOD   22737    30966    24660
2   AVALFAED   AVALFAED[+16]       2    hydroxy   40060     2423     3553
3   AVALFAED   AVALFAE[+16]D       2    hydroxy   40131     2407     3577
4   AVALFAED        AVALFAED       2      UNMOD   21962    34387    29860
5   AVALFAED   AVALFAED[-30]       3   decarbox      12       16       40
6   AVALFAED        AVALFAED       3      UNMOD   21885    35444    33511
7   AVALFAED        AVALFAED       4      UNMOD    2116     3072     2974
```

Specifically, I want to calculate new columns for the "fraction unmodified" of each modified sequence (essentially every row), and then expand this across multiple "area" columns.

fracUnmod = (1- (area_modified / (area_modified + area_unmodified)))

The "area_unmodified" values have to come from different rows, so I can't seem to figure out a way to do this using a function like `df.concat()` or `df.insert()`.
The correct "area_unmodified" values are determined from the row which shares the same 'baseSeq' and 'charge' values, but without any modification (I included a column 'modType' for convenience).

I don't have to calculate fracUnmod for the unmodified rows, but I don't want to drop these rows from my resulting output (leaving them in just gives fracUnmod = 0.5, which is fine).

Sometimes there are rows where no unmodified version is found (not shown), but I left those out since I'm aware of the preference that I ask secondary questions in a separate post, plus I've been able to filter them out manually in Excel.

I've been doing something like this, looping thru each row:

```
for X in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('area')].tolist():
    df[X.replace('area', 'fracUnmod')] = ''
for row in df.index:
    for X in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('area')].tolist():
        Y = X.replace('area', 'fracUnmod')
        df[Y].iloc[row] = (1 - ((df.iloc[row][X]) / ((df.iloc[row][X]) + (df[(df.baseSeq==df.iloc[row].baseSeq) & (df.charge==df.iloc[row].charge) & (df.baseSeq==df.modSeq)][X].item()))))
```

It works, but it takes a long time (~10 min) for my complete dataset (650 rows for "row" to loop thru, 10 "area" columns for "X" to loop thru).

I'm also raising that pesky "SettingWithCopyWarning" -- do I avoid this by appending `.ascopy()` to the "Chained Assignment" of my last line? I've never been able to figure this out.

I've read several times that loops should be avoided whenever possible, so I'm guessing this is the problem.
Is there a cleaner and faster way to do this?

Each combination of 'modSeq' and 'charge' is unique, so maybe I'd want to do something with `df.groupby()` or `df.merge()`, and use a temporary DF?

I come across this situation often, so I'm looking to learn how I can do this sort of thing without using loops (or at least increase the speed).

Answer (score 0):

If we create some temporary columns, it is possible to vectorize your math operation, and this should drastically cut down on the amount of time. Afterwards we can delete the temporary columns.

Using the example you gave, it looks like this:

1. We start with a `df` that looks like this:

```
    baseSeq    modSeq        charge     modType   area_0  area_25   area_50
0   ADTPICR    ADT[+16]PICR       2     hydoxy      1862     2472      3015
1   ADTPICR    ADTPICR            2     UNMOD      22737    30966     24660
2   AVALFAED   AVALFAED[+16]      2     hydroxy    40060     2423      3553
3   AVALFAED   AVALFAE[+16]D      2     hydroxy    40131     2407      3577
4   AVALFAED   AVALFAED           2     UNMOD      21962    34387     29860
5   AVALFAED   AVALFAED[-30]      3     decarbox      12       16        40
6   AVALFAED   AVALFAED           3     UNMOD      21885    35444     33511
7   AVALFAED   AVALFAED           4     UNMOD       2116     3072      2974
```

2. Create a list of all the 'area' columns:

   `area_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('area')].tolist()`
3. The following 5 lines of code create a temporary df that contains the *un-modded* areas for each `baseSeq`/`charge` combo:

```
temp_df = df[['baseSeq'] + ['charge'] + ['modType'] + area_cols].groupby(['baseSeq', 'charge', 'modType'], axis=0).sum()
temp_df = temp_df.reset_index(level=2)
temp_df = temp_df[temp_df['modType'] == 'UNMOD']
temp_df = temp_df.drop('modType', axis=1)
temp_df.rename(columns = lambda x: 'unmod_' + x, inplace=True)
```

Here is what the temporary df looks like at this point:

```
                unmod_area_0    unmod_area_25   unmod_area_50
baseSeq  charge         
ADTPICR       2        22737            30966          24660
AVALFAED      2        21962            34387          29860
              3        21885            35444          33511
              4         2116             3072           2974
```

4. We then join this temporary dataframe back to our main dataframe, in order to have columns that display the proper amount of un-modded areas for each `baseSeq`/`charge` combo:

   `df = df.join(temp_df, on=['baseSeq', 'charge'])`
5. At this point, our dataframe looks like this:

```
    baseSeq     modSeq       charge  modType    area_0  area_25 area_50 unmod_area_0    unmod_area_25   unmod_area_50
0   ADTPICR     ADT[+16]PICR      2  hydoxy       1862     2472    3015        22737            30966           24660
1   ADTPICR     ADTPICR           2  UNMOD       22737    30966   24660        22737            30966           24660
2   AVALFAED    AVALFAED[+16]     2  hydroxy     40060     2423    3553        21962            34387           29860
3   AVALFAED    AVALFAE[+16]D     2  hydroxy     40131     2407    3577        21962            34387           29860
4   AVALFAED    AVALFAED          2  UNMOD       21962    34387   29860        21962            34387           29860
5   AVALFAED    AVALFAED[-30]     3  decarbox       12       16      40        21885            35444           33511
6   AVALFAED    AVALFAED          3  UNMOD       21885    35444   33511        21885            35444           33511
7   AVALFAED    AVALFAED          4  UNMOD        2116     3072    2974         2116             3072            2974
```

6. Now for the main part: we loop over each 'area' column and calculate the desired fraction. This calculation is *vectorized* across each row of a column, and should considerably speed things up.

```
for col in area_cols:
    num = col.split('_')[1]
    df['fracUnmod_' + num] = 1 - (df[col] / (df[col] + df['unmod_' + col]))
```

7. To clean things up, let's finish by dropping the temporary columns that display the unmodded areas, and delete our temp dataframe.

   `df = df.drop(['unmod_' + c for c in area_cols], axis=1)`

   `del(temp_df)`

   The final dataframe looks like this:

```
    baseSeq     modSeq       charge  modType    area_0  area_25 area_50 fracUnmod_0  fracUnmod_25   fracUnmod_50
0   ADTPICR     ADT[+16]PICR      2  hydoxy       1862     2472    3015    0.924306      0.926072       0.891057
1   ADTPICR     ADTPICR           2  UNMOD       22737    30966   24660    0.500000      0.500000       0.500000
2   AVALFAED    AVALFAED[+16]     2  hydroxy     40060     2423    3553    0.354100      0.934175       0.893664
3   AVALFAED    AVALFAE[+16]D     2  hydroxy     40131     2407    3577    0.353695      0.934582       0.893023
4   AVALFAED    AVALFAED          2  UNMOD       21962    34387   29860    0.500000      0.500000       0.500000
5   AVALFAED    AVALFAED[-30]     3  decarbox       12       16      40    0.999452      0.999549       0.998808
6   AVALFAED    AVALFAED          3  UNMOD       21885    35444   33511    0.500000      0.500000       0.500000
7   AVALFAED    AVALFAED          4  UNMOD        2116     3072    2974    0.500000      0.500000       0.500000
```

This is the same output that your original nested for-loop produced. But should hopefully be much faster.